# Omit or pick specific properties on save() with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, lodash

So, I `save()` a document in mongoose and send a response back to the client with the saved document, but let's say I want to pick or omit some properties of the data I send to the client, how should I do this **in a right way**?

```
// blablabla
someDoc = await page.save()
res.send(someDoc)
```

Now, I can't simply `delete` a property of the `someDoc` like so:

```
someDoc = await page.save()
delete someDoc.propName
res.send(someDoc)
```

But if I deep copy the `someDoc` and make manipulations on it, I can(dah).

I also can't make use of lodash here if I do like so, it simply not working:

```
someDoc = await page.save()
_.pick(someDoc , ["propName"]);
res.send(someDoc)
```

So, firstly I don't really get it, why am I not able to mutate the original `someDoc` from the first place? Why the changes are not apply to the `someDoc` I send to the client?

Secondly, why the heck is lodash not working like in the prev. example?

And finally, what is the best practice in this kind of scenario, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert the result of page.save() to object after that delete a field like this:

```
result = await page.save()
let someDoc = result.toObject()
delete someDoc.propName
res.send(someDoc)
```

Comment: But how the heck is that possible, dude... I checked the `typeof` of the original `someDoc`(your `result`) and it says `object`! What the actual...? what am I missing here?

Comment: the typeof of save is Model of Schema not an object, you should convert to model to an object after that delete a field

Comment: is not your problem solved with my answer?

Comment: I want to understand the "why", bro... not simply "solve" it. I could solve it on my own in at least one another way I mentioned in my post.

Comment: the result of save() or find() or findOne or... in mongoose is a mongoose document , not a plain JavaScript object. if you want a plain JavaScript object you should convert it, with .`toObject ()` (it works for  a  mongoose document ) and .`lean()` ( it works for  a  mongoose documents for result of find query), if you review the result of console.log(result ) and console.log(someDoc) you will understand